# Android Studio start failed with error caused by java.io.EOFException

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After updating the Android Studio, start failed with these popbox, if anyone knows how to solve this problem ,I would really appreciate that.

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.AssertionError: Internal file was corrupted. Problem is fixed.
If some plugins has been installed/uninstalled, please re-install/-uninstall them.
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:132)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.StartupActionScriptManager.loadActionScript(StartupActionScriptManager.java:84)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.StartupActionScriptManager.executeActionScript(StartupActionScriptManager.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ide.BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.initClassLoader(BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:32)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:92)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.StartupActionScriptManager.loadActionScript(StartupActionScriptManager.java:78)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: You should follow the instructions... `Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues`

Comment: @cricket_007 , if I can, I'll do that, In china, we cann't link to google.com, so is there anything else I can do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at last, I solve this problem by myself. just to delete some files will solve the problems. 
.android  and   .AndroidStudio1.4   these two files'directory is C:\Users\USER_NAME

Comment: Thanks - had a similar problem where I got an EOF Exception after a hard restart.  After deleting those two folders, my problem was solved.

Comment: And if you're using Mac then you will find this folder in Users\USER_NAME (show hidden folders using *cmd+sft+*.)

Answer (score 1):

For me, toggling gradle offline mode on solved the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can restart Android Studio also cleaning cache:

[image: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...]